# Polygon Intersection on map shows offset

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, turfjs

I'm trying to find intersection area between 2 polygons drawn on a map.
I've TurfJS intersect method to find intersection between 2 polygons.

It works good for smaller areas but for larger area polygons it starts showing some offset at the intersection points, the offset grows as the distance grows.
This is also seen only for polygons with slanting lines (vertical and horizontal line intersections seem to work well).

I've created a JSFiddle for this : https://jsfiddle.net/cLe6yo9d/

I'm trying to find the intersection between the black and blue polygons, what I get is shown as the red polygon which is seen shifted from where it should be.

```
var mapLayer = L.map('mapid', {
 zoomAnimation: false
});
var pid = 'karan44.pdmio34k';
var at = 'pk.mapbox-access-token-goes-here';
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  id: pid,
  accessToken: at
}).addTo(mapLayer);

var polygon1 = turf.polygon([
  [
    [3.405762, 51.395350],
    [5.009766, 53.340303],
    [7.141113, 53.653999],
    [5.822754, 51.037508],
    [3.405762, 51.395350]
  ]
], {
  "fill": "#00000F",
  "stroke": "#00000F",
  "stroke-width": 1
});

var polygon2 = turf.polygon([
  [
    [0.241699, 54.173488],
    [10.162354, 50.908012],
    [8.854980, 50.062208],
    [0.241699, 54.173488]
  ]
], {
  "fill": "#0000FF",
  "stroke": "#0000FF",
  "stroke-width": 1
});

var polygon = turf.intersect(polygon1, polygon2);
polygon.properties = {
  "fill": "#FF0000",
  "stroke": "#FF0000",
  "stroke-width": 1
};


L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon1).addTo(mapLayer);
L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon2).addTo(mapLayer);

L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon).addTo(mapLayer);
mapLayer.setView([52.754260888947776, 5.72100021667583], 8);
```

This fiddle has been created by modifying [turf.intersect example](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-intersect/) to reproduce the issue.

Hoping someone could help me understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue came back again, and finally found the solution to it. Sharing just in case it might be helpful to someone else.

What I understood about the issue is that turf.js and LeafletJs use different projection systems. So I manually projected coordinates to EPSG:3857 before passing to turfjs methods and then transforming turfjs result back to EPSG:4326 before passing to Leaflet.

https://jsfiddle.net/5Ls3vw8d/

```
var mapLayer = L.map('mapid', {
    zoomAnimation: false
});
var pid = 'karan44.pdmio34k';
var at = 'pk.mapbox-access-token-goes-here';
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  id: pid,
  accessToken: at
}).addTo(mapLayer);
//Construct Truf projection polygons
var polygon1 = turf.polygon([[
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[3.405762, 51.395350]),
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[5.009766, 53.340303]),
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[7.141113, 53.653999]),
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[5.822754, 51.037508]),
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[3.405762, 51.395350])
]], {
  "fill": "#00000F",
  "stroke": "#00000F",
  "stroke-width": 1
});
var polygon2 = turf.polygon([[
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[0.241699, 54.173488]),
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[10.162354, 50.908012]),
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[8.854980, 50.062208]),
    proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857",[0.241699, 54.173488])
]], {
  "fill": "#0000FF",
  "stroke": "#0000FF",
  "stroke-width": 1
});
var polygon = turf.intersect(polygon1, polygon2);
polygon.properties = {
  "fill": "#FF0000",
  "stroke": "#FF0000",
  "stroke-width": 1
};
//Convert all polygons back to Leaflet projection
for(var i in polygon1.geometry.coordinates[0]) {
    polygon1.geometry.coordinates[0][i] = proj4("EPSG:3857","EPSG:4326",polygon1.geometry.coordinates[0][i]);
}
for(var i in polygon2.geometry.coordinates[0]) {
    polygon2.geometry.coordinates[0][i] = proj4("EPSG:3857","EPSG:4326",polygon2.geometry.coordinates[0][i]);
}
for(var i in polygon.geometry.coordinates[0]) {
    polygon.geometry.coordinates[0][i] = proj4("EPSG:3857","EPSG:4326",polygon.geometry.coordinates[0][i]);
}
L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon1).addTo(mapLayer);
L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon2).addTo(mapLayer);
L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon).addTo(mapLayer);
mapLayer.setView([52.754260888947776, 5.72100021667583], 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me just what turf is doing when it calculates the intersections (they do not lie on great circles between the polygon vertices as Ivan had suspected), but the problem can be solved by interpolating polygons along great circle arcs, then using `turf.intersect` on those. The function below will take GeoJSON polygons (like those produced with `turf.polygon`) and output new polygons with each edge interpolated to a geodesic arc (optionally specifying a number of steps to use):

```js
//interpolates simple GeoJSON polygon features along geodesic arcs
function geodesify(input, steps) {
  if (typeof steps === 'undefined') {
    steps = 50; //interpolation steps on each segment
  }
  var tempLine = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": []
    },
    "properties": {}
  }
  if (input.geometry.type === "Polygon") {
    tempLine.geometry.coordinates = input.geometry.coordinates[0];
    tempLine.properties = input.properties;
    tempLine.properties.geodesic = "true"; //tells Leaflet.Geodesic to interpolate this feature
    tempLine.properties.geodesic_steps = steps;
    var geoLine = L.geoJson(tempLine).toGeoJSON();//convert interpolated feature back to GeoJSON
    var output = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": geoLine.features[0].geometry.coordinates
      },
      "properties": tempLine.properties
    };
    output.properties.geodesic = "false"; //to prevent a second interpolation
    var outLen = output.geometry.coordinates[0].length;
    output.geometry.coordinates[0][outLen-1] = output.geometry.coordinates[0][0];
    return output;
  }
  console.log("geodesify input geometry must be a GeoJSON Polygon Feature");
  return false;
}
```

It relies on the [`Leaflet.Geodesic` plugin](https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic), which will interpolate GeoJSON LineString features that have a property called `geodesic` set to `"true"`. Most of this code is spent converting the GeoJSON from Polygon to LineString and back to Polygon, which would be unnecessary if the plugin accepted Polygon features to begin with. But anyway, in your example, you would use it like this:

```js
var polygon1a = geodesify(polygon1, 30);
var polygon2a = geodesify(polygon2, 30);

var polygon = turf.intersect(polygon1a, polygon2a);
polygon.properties = {
  "fill": "#FF0000",
  "stroke": "#FF0000",
  "stroke-width": 1
};

L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon1a).addTo(mapLayer);
L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon2a).addTo(mapLayer);

L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(polygon).addTo(mapLayer);
```

Here is a fiddle showing it at work:

https://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/ycnno5df/

It's important to note that this function only works if the input is a single GeoJSON `Polygon` feature, though it could be adapted to work with other types.
The use of Leaflet.Geodesic might be overkill here, but it works. I suspect that any sufficiently fine interpolation would actually work fine (that is, turf would calculate intersections that fall along the polygon edges when drawn on the map), but this method has the advantage of being geographically correct.

Comment: Thanks @nathansnider for sharing this example which looks much better, but If I zoom in to full extent there still is a minor offset. From what I observed so far the longer a point of the polygon is from the intersection the more the offset is, as you converted it to a curve adding points in between which reduced the distance of the polygon point form the intersection, hence reducing the offset. (or maybe its correct because of great circle?). 
I am needing this to be exactly adjacent as I'm trying to create adjacent polygons with connected sides being exactly same.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to round/approximate these points over the intersecting line ?

Comment: You are correct that the larger the distance between points, the greater the offset will be. The problem is clearly a bug in turf, as the calculated intersection is offset to the south, while the true great circle intersection actually lies to the north. If you increase the steps parameter (e.g. `geodesify(polygon1, 100)`), the offset can be reduced to a negligible amount.

Comment: While it is not too difficult to calculate the geometric intersection points (that is, the points where lines *on the map* intersect) by converting to projected coordinates first, calculating the full polygon intersection is a bit more complicated. [Here is an example](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/171305/56906) of calculating the intersection points in projected coordinate space. Note that the suggested solution using turf there has the same bug, but I guess nobody zoomed in far enough to notice.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because straight lines on a (projected) map don't equal straight lines on the surface of the earth (or, in other words, [great circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) on the sirface of a geoid).

See [some great circles](http://mad-gooze.github.io/Leaflet.Arc/) for a graphical explanation.

I encourage you to draw your big polygons with great circles instead of lines and see if the intersections make more sense.

Comment: It looks like the problem may be something else. Here's a comparison with some great circles from Leaflet.Geodesic: https://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/wjpyuLeL/ The great circles (in white) are actually bowed upward on the map, while the turf intersections are offset downward.